# How can I create a button with isHidden code and get UIAlert when it be pressed? and be visible after that - swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertview, hidden

How do I create an hidden button? When I press the button, it creates a UIAlert and asks if I want to buy the product. And when I buy the product, the button will be visible?

Answer (score 1):

If a button is hidden, it is not clickable. Instead, you may want to create a "clear" button. When you press the button, popup the UIAlert and make the button not clear.